# Удаление элемента из коллекции Kotlin

Tags: массивы, kotlin, коллекции

ДД!
Имеется коллекция объектов: post1, post2 и тд...

```
private var posts = mutableListOf<Post>()
```

Добавляю элементы.
Далее пытаюсь реализовать функцию удаления элемента из коллекции:

```
    override fun delete(post: Post): Boolean {
        for (target in posts) {
            if (post.id == target.id) {
                posts.remove(target)
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Но при попытке удаления элемента

```
delete(post1)
```

элемент не удаляется и функция возврящает false.
Может кто подскажет в чем у меня проблема?
[ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/filin2hat/PowtNew/tree/addNote/src/main/kotlin)

Comment: добавь в цикл вывод post.id и target.id и смотри что там происходит

Comment: Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в самом вопросе вместе с входными данными (содержимым posts и post).

Comment: Самое простое - это считать индексы при поиске по `id`, а затем удалять не по элементу, а по индексу при помощи `removeAt`.

Comment: Ваш код написан опасно, предполагаю, что у вас при некоторых обстоятельствах будет [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353395).

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, спасибо за ваши подсказки. Я понял в чем моя проблема. Я не правильно передавал объект в функцию.
Тяжело в учении - легко в бою )